# redirect user after writing data to their account

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I was wondering how I can redirect my users to their dashboard after their account is added to the real time database. Currently, it redirects them before the function can be completed.

```
function signUp()
{
    var email = document.getElementById("usernameS").value;
    var password = document.getElementById("passwordS").value;
    console.log(email);
    console.log(password);
    firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .then((userCredential) =>
    {
        var user = userCredential.user;
        firebase.database().ref('users/' + user.uid).set
        ({
            email: email
        });
        redirect();
    })
    .catch((error) => 
    {
        var errorCode = error.code;
        var errorMessage = error.message;
        console.log(errorMessage);
    });
}

function redirect()
{
    window.location.replace('dashboard.html');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Set is a promise so try moving the redirect to inside a then callback which would help ensure set has completed before attempting to redirect:

```
return firebase.database().ref('users/' + user.uid).set({ existing stuff }).then(() => redirect());
```

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: Hopefully this will help.

Comment: thank you so much. I've been trying to work around stuff like this for ages. I didn't know there was a then function which made life so much easier